# Find $a\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n^4+a$ is not prime $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

How would I go about finding such an $a$?

I've been thinking it is something to do with modular arithmetic, but don't know what base to consider.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$n^4 + b^4 = (n^2-\sqrt{2}nb+b^2)(n^2+\sqrt{2}nb+b^2)$. Set $b = 2\sqrt{2}$. Then, $n^4 + 64= (n^2-4n+8)(n^2+4n+8)$.

(... and it can be verified that both factors are greater than $1$ for every $n\geq 1$)

Comment: +1 for explaining how you got to the answer, rather than just posting the last line (which would have sufficed!)

Comment: (I guess that one should still check that neither factor is $1$, for any value of $n$)

Comment: Haha, thank you. I had that expansion in mind, but actually wasn't sure it would really work. Took me a while to determine how to choose $b$. Regarding $n$, yes; one should check it, left to the reader (it is not very difficult to check it) :)

Comment: Thanks a million. Is there a generic formula for factorising $a^n+b^n$ or did you just happen to know this factorisation would work?

Comment: @SalamanderSylph I guess the fourth power case is somewhat special as you have this kind of formula (but I am not an expert on these things so don't trust my word). For odd powers, you may the well known factorization (e.g. check out wiki), $a^{2n+1}+b^{2n+1} = (a+b)\cdots$ will probably work (to solve your kind of problem). So, we can I guess handle for $n=3,4$ and every other odd $n$. The remaining $n\neq1,2$s are either powers of $2$ (this case is ok as these $n$ are of the form $4k$, or a power of $2$ times an odd number (this case also looks ok).

Comment: Wow this exact same question appeared in an example sheet I finished a month ago; anyway @SalamanderSylph see [Sophie Germain identity](http://topologicalmusings.wordpress.com/2008/02/20/sophie-germain-identity/)